# "I have not had an answer" - what is the real meaning?

Tags: meaning

I've been told that when someone says or e.g. writes in an e-mail: *"I have not had an answer."*, - it means they are very angry.
Is this so?

thanks for an answer:)

Comment: I would think they could be anything from slightly irritated to very angry.

Comment: Depends entirely on the context.

Comment: It might be true, but I wouldn't assume so.

Comment: Thank you! The whole sentence was: "I haven’t received your answer about our Xmas coffee."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.  It's not really helpful to those responding to the question to provide a sentence fragment with different wording in the absence of any context.  Please follow [this link](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on asking good questions.

Comment: @Bonavira, then it probably means "You haven't told me what your answer is; please tell me". It doesn't necessarily mean that they're angry.

Answer (score 3):

If I was wanting to be polite I would always say 'I do not appear to have received an answer about the Xmas coffee'. It leaves open the possibility that they may have answered but I have overlooked their reply.

Yes, if someone bluntly says 'I haven't received your answer' it does sound a trifle brusque. It is not really rude, but they are clearly not going to too much trouble to be polite.

Comment: Thank you all! The point is that a conversation was between 2 people who know each other for 4 years, kind of a pretty friendship relation though. One of them - me, the other one - an English native.I have never lived in an English spoken country. I'll keep in mind all your answers and explanation:) I am glad I have found this forum:)